# RestKit: mapping to NSDictionary with values of specific type

Tags: ios, restkit, restkit-0.20

I've got the following JSON coming from my webservice:

```
  "GasPrices":{
     "Ai92":{
        "Price":30.1000,
        "LastDate":"\/Date(1385337600000)\/",
        "Votes":0
     },
     "Ai95":{
        "Price":33.2000,
        "LastDate":"\/Date(1385337600000)\/",
        "Votes":0
     }
```

I want to map it to `NSDictionary`, whose keys would be `NSString`s and values would be of my custom class, say, `PriceInfo`.

What I got now with default setup is NSDictionary whose values are also NSDictionaries.

How can I achieve the desired mapping?

**UPD.** Here's my full setup for now.

```
@interface FillingStation : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *uid;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *fuelPrices;
@end

@interface PriceInfo : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *price;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate *lastDate;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *votes;
@end
```

Configuring the mapping:

```
RKObjectMapping *mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[FillingStation class]];
[mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
        @"Id" : @"uid",
        @"Title" : @"title",
        @"GasPrices" : @"fuelPrices"
}];
```

This results in `fuelPrices` is `NSDictionary` with the structure:

```
NSString -> NSDictionary,
NSString -> NSDictionary,
...
```

And I want it to be:

```
NSString -> PriceInfo,
NSString -> PriceInfo,
...
```

And I don't want an intermediate dictionary in `FillingStation` which I can then manually map.

Comment: we can check for `NSString` but what do you exactly mean by `"values would be of my custom class, say, PriceInfo"`

Comment: I've declared a class `PriceInfo` with properties `price`, `lastDate` and `votes`, and I want values of `GasPrices` dictionary to map to objects of `PriceInfo` class

Comment: so basically, pick up the info and dump it in a class (with all values being `NSString` only) ?

Comment: I've updated the question to make my intensions more obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, seems like I found the answer. Not exactly what I wanted, yet acceptable for me: https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-Mapping#handling-dynamic-nesting-attributes

I had to add another property to `PriceInfo` class and change `fuelPrices` from `NSDictionary` to `NSSet` (`NSArray` would also work, but I don't need ordering), so it became:

```
@interface FillingStation : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *uid;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSSet *fuelPrices;
@end

@interface PriceInfo : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *fuelType;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *price;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate *updateDate;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSUInteger votes;
@end
```

and my mapping now looks like this:

```
RKObjectMapping *mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[FillingStation class]];
[mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
        @"Id" : @"uid",
        @"Title" : @"title"
}];

RKObjectMapping *priceInfoMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[PriceInfo class]];
[priceInfoMapping setForceCollectionMapping:YES];
[priceInfoMapping addAttributeMappingFromKeyOfRepresentationToAttribute:@"fuelType"];
[priceInfoMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
        @"(fuelType).Price": @"price",
        @"(fuelType).LastDate": @"updateDate",
        @"(fuelType).Votes": @"votes"
}];

[mapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"GasPrices"
                                                                        toKeyPath:@"fuelPrices"
                                                                      withMapping:priceInfoMapping]];
```

Answer (score 0):

[Jastor](http://www.devign.me/jastor-json-nsdictionary-to-objective-c-class/) May be what you're looking for.  Nested objects directly mapped to known classes.

Comment: Sounds like I need to do a lot of manual work with it. I was hoping that there is some way to do that using just RestKit.